# How to implement a band-pass filter in c# / Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, audio, synthesis

How would I go about implementing a band-pass filter in c#?  I'm using a custom MediaStreamSource in Silverlight and am using additive synthesis to produce sound.  My audio stream is a continuous stream of int16 shorts:

```
//over-simplified example:
short sample = oscillator.GetNextSample();
memoryStream.WriteByte((byte)(sample & 0xFF));
memoryStream.WriteByte((byte)(sample >> 8));
```

...where "sample" is a function of a sine calculation (or some other complex combination of waveforms) ranging from short.MinValue to short.MaxValue.

I have no idea where to start with a band-pass filter.  How would I go about implementing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this is what I'm looking for:

[Low pass filter software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344343/low-pass-filter-software)

I haven't tried it yet, but that is the raw calculation example I was hoping to find.  It looks like I'll need to revise that code to work with Int16's instead of doubles, and it also looks like I have a lot of dirty work ahead of me for defining the particular constants/coefficients I'll need, but it should get me started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228659/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-continuously-sample-from-the-line-in-using-c), in particular you might find [Jacob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228659/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-continuously-sample-from-the-line-in-using-c/228693#228693) useful.

Comment: I'm not sure how well those responses will translate to my Silverlight app since they seem to be aimed toward managed DirectX or unmanaged libraries - both of which are not available in my context.  I'm hoping to find some more "raw" computation examples.  Those responses may help though - I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

puhh this is math , isn´t it ;-)
So I guess its System.Math
and read this free [book](http://uploaded.to/file/ity83g)

Comment: Ren - could you try to put that file on a "better" free upload site like http://drop.io?  the uploaded.to link is nagging me with wait times and the file never downloads.

Comment: sorry it´s no upload from me, from this site
http://freebooksource.com/blogroll/engineering-technology/signal-analysis-wavelets-filter-banks-time-frequency-transforms-and-applications/